# How to start page numbering from 2 rather 1

Tags: pandoc

I can not figure out how is it possible to start page numbering from 2 rather 1, i.e 2, 3, 4, ..., in Pandoc when converting to PDF?

Answer (score 3):

Pandoc relies on LaTeX for PDF generation, and you can write [inline/raw TeX](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-tex). So try inserting the following at the beginning of your document:

```
\setcounter{page}{2}
```

Comment: This one works for me.
One could also use "header-includes" yaml attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc produces pdf through latex. You need to add `\setcounter{page}{2}` to your file. You could also create an option that allows you to set the starting page number in your yaml header.

1. edit `~/.pandoc/templates/default.latex` (or create it : `pandoc -D latex > ~/.pandoc/templates/default.latex`
2. add the following lines in the header:

   ```
   $if(start-page)$
   \setcounter{page}{$start-page$}
   $endif$
   ```
3. Add the following your document yaml header

   ```
   ---
   start-page: 2
   ---
   ```
4. Compile with the usual options, e.g. `pandoc mydoc.md -o mydoc.pdf`